# Knapsack: The simplest way to solve a LP with just one constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Definition:

A Knapsack problem is a LP which has only $1$ constraint.
For example:

$Max \space\space z=x_1+2x_2+4x_3$
$s.t \space\space 2x_1+3x_3 \le 5$

(Assume that $\forall i \space\space x_i \ge 0$ )

Usually, When i face this, The simplex method is the first thing which comes to my mind.  But, I read somewhere that these problems which have just $1$ constraint, are called Knapsack problems.  Now, My Question is:

> Is there any simpler method to solve Knapsack problems? (Simpler than
>   the usual way like simplex method)

Comment: Do you have a reference for that name? I've never seen it used in that context -- namely, a Knapsack problem in computer science is what you stated, with integral constraints (so it's not a LP anymore): $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i$.

Comment: @ClementC. Its not a book... Its from the lecture notes of one of my teachers... ( Which is not available on the internet! ) I know that knapsack problem you are speaking of... Anyway, the name is not important... The question is valid... don't you agree with me? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the given example is trivial: the problem is unbounded as you can set $x_2$ to $+ \infty$.

For the general case: let $c_i$ and $w_i$ denote the cost and weight of item $i$ respectively, and $b$ the upper bound of the knapsack constraint.

1. Order the items by non increasing order of the ratio $c_i/w_i$.
2. WLOG, suppose item $1$ comes first in the list.
3. Set $x_1 = b/w_1$ and $x_i =0, i>1.$

   The idea is to select the items with best cost and least volume in priority.

Comment: I'm not talking about just one example! The question is general!

Comment: Ok! Have edited a solution for the general case.

Comment: Thanks! What a great way to solve the problem! Awesome!

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade For reference (and keyword): this is the *greedy algorithm* for the Knapsack problem (see e.g. [these lecture notes](https://home.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L14/L14.pdf). It works well for the fractional Knapsack problem (where $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for all $i$, but is not good for the "real" Knapsack problem (where you have integral constraints $x_i\in\{0,1\}$).